# Playable Game Area in Swift 3.0

Tags: swift, macos, sprite-kit

I'm creating a mario clone for mac to help me learn swift programming. An issue I have come across is setting a playable game area. As of now, the 2 backgrounds I have ("background" and "level") will move when the left or right keys are pressed but grey areas at the sides will become visible. I want to be able to make the backgrounds move, but set an area at which they will stop moving.

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    let player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "mario")

    let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")

    let level = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "level")

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

        //self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)

        level.size = self.size
        level.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height/2)
        level.zPosition = 1
        self.addChild(level)

        background.size = self.size
        background.position = CGPoint(x: level.size.width + 511, y: self.size.height/2)
        background.zPosition = 0
        self.addChild(background)

        player.setScale(0.23)
        player.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/8, y: 120)
        player.zPosition = 2
        self.addChild(player)

    }

    override func keyDown(with theEvent: NSEvent) {
        let keyCode = theEvent.keyCode

        //Moving Right
        if keyCode == 124 {
            level.run(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.moveBy(x: -20, y: 0, duration: 0.2)]))

            background.run(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.moveBy(x: -20, y: 0, duration: 0.2)]))

            player.xScale = 0.23
        }

        //Moving Left
        if keyCode == 123 {
            background.run(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.moveBy(x: 20, y: 0, duration: 0.2)]))

            level.run(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.moveBy(x: 20, y: 0, duration: 0.2)]))

            player.xScale = -0.23        
        }

        //Jump
        if keyCode == 126{            
             player.run(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.moveTo(y: 250, duration: 0.15),SKAction.moveTo(y: 120, duration: 0.2)]))
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there is a much better, more clever solution, but off the top of my head you could add:

```
let LEFTBOUND: Int = //Insert the left limit here.
let RIGHTBOUND: Int = //Insert the right limit here.
```

Inside `func keyDown()`, in the moving right/left if-statements, nest these:

```
if level.position.x < RIGHTBOUND:
    //Move level so long as it is less than the RIGHTBOUND value.
    //TODO: set the level.position to RIGHTBOUND so it doesn't keep updating with new values while keyDown is true.

if level.position.x > LEFTBOUND:
    //Move level so long as it is greater than the LEFTBOUND value.
    //TODO: set the level.position to LEFTBOUND so it doesn't keep updating with new values while the keyDown is true.

//Repeat theses steps for background.position.x
```

You should also restrict the player movement so the player doesn't run out of the level unrecoverably.

Comment: there is,  use a camera, then we do not have to ever worry about moving the level

Comment: @Knight0fDragon thanks! Way more elegant. Just have the camera follow the player, right?

Comment: actually I would probably have the character as a child of camera,  and when a wall is hit, the character position would move against the camera

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I like that suggestion, hopefully OP is reading.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Thanks for the response and ideas guys! I will definitely look into the camera method. As of now I used a solution based on NonCreature's idea. Really appreciate the help. Cheers.

Comment: @MarioMan hey! Glad I helped you! If I answered you question, could you accept it? Thanks!